# Filter text between quotes or < >

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I need an expression using *SED* or similar that will allow to retrieve text between quotes or greater-than and less-than symbols. I tried a few variations of *SED* but could not quite get the output to only list the domains.

```
Matches: list:"<alumni.lists.org>"
Do this: Apply label "MailingLists" edit     delete
Matches: list:"w3.domain.org"
Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply label "MailingLists" edit     delete
```

Comment: @ObscureRobot I was trying to manipulate _$ sed '/\[[^]]/s/^[^[]*\<\([^]]*\)>.*$/\1/p' mail-list_

Comment: will every line have at most one segment of text between quotes or <>, or can a line have multiple?

Comment: @aleph_null Correction, "MailingLists" on every other line would also match but it is unwanted output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

Input:

```
Matches: list:"<alumni.lists.org>"
Do this: Apply label "MailingLists" edit     delete
Matches: list:"w3.domain.org"
Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply label "MailingLists" edit     delete
```

Command:

```
sed 's/.*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/;s/<\([^>]*\)>/\1/' file
```

Output:

```
alumni.lists.org
MailingLists
w3.domain.org
MailingLists
```

EDIT:

```
sed 's/.*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/;s/<\([^>]*\)>/\1/' file | egrep "\.[a-z]{1,3}$"
```

Output:

```
alumni.lists.org
w3.domain.org
```

HTH Chris

Comment: Is there a way to do away with printing **MailingLists**?

Comment: Is it necessary to invoke egrep? Surely `/MailingLists/d` is suffice.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
sed '/MailingLists/d;s/.*"<\?\([^">]*\)>\?".*/\1/;' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with following regexp:

```
/<([^>]+)>|"([^"]+)"/
```

Comment: $ sed '/<([^>]+)>|"([^"]+)"/' mail-list
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: missing command